# Dissect a byte array into distinct data types?

Tags: java

I am using the `Naga` library to read data from a socket, which produces `byte[]` arrays which are received via a delegate function.

My question is, how can I convert this byte array into specific data types, knowing the alignment?

*For example, if the byte array contains the following data, in order:*

```
| byte | byte | short | byte | int | int |
```

How can I extract those data types (in **little endian**)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest you have a look at the `ByteBuffer` class (specifically the [`ByteBuffer.wrap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28byte%5b%5d%29) method and the various `getXxx` methods).

**Example class**:

```
class Packet {

    byte field1;
    byte field2;
    short field3;
    byte field4;
    int field5;
    int field6;

    public Packet(byte[] data) {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data)
                                   .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        field1 = buf.get();
        field2 = buf.get();
        field3 = buf.getShort();
        field4 = buf.get();
        field5 = buf.getInt();
        field6 = buf.getInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using [ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [ScatteringByteChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ScatteringByteChannel.html) like so :

```
ByteBuffer one = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
ByteBuffer two   = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
ByteBuffer three = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
ByteBuffer four   = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
ByteBuffer five = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
ByteBuffer six   = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

ByteBuffer[] bufferArray = { one, two, three, four, five, six };
channel.read(bufferArray);
```