# Byte based (de)serialization in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I want to try abusing Java classes as structures and for that I'm wondering if it is possible to serialize a byte array to a class and other way around.

So if I have a class like this:

```
public class Handshake
{
    byte command;
    byte error;
    short size;
    int major;
    int ts;
    char[] secret; // aligned size = 32 bytes
}
```

Is there an easy way (without having to manually read bytes and fill out the class which requires 3 times as much code) to **deserialize** a set of bytes into this class? I know that Java doesn't have structs but I'm wondering if it is possible to simplify the serialization process so it does it automatically. **The bytes are not from Java's serializer, they are just aligned bytes derived from C structs.**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what **exactly** is the difference between this question and [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899720/dissect-a-byte-array-into-distinct-data-types)?

Comment: This is treading awfully close to being a duplicate of your own questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891663/is-it-possible-to-use-struct-like-constructs-in-java.

Comment: I'm still trying to find out if I can achieve this sort of thing in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The bytes are not from Java's serializer, they are just aligned bytes
>   derived from C structs.

Bad idea. It can break as soon as someone compiles that code on a different platform, using a different compiler or settings, etc.

Much better: use a standardized binary interface with implementations in Java and C++ like ASN.1 or Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/protocolbuffers/).

Comment: The client's protocol is well defined and isn't going to be changed in the near future.

Comment: @Nick Brooks that implies that it must be defined some way other than via C structs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a library to do the deserializtion using reflection.  This may result in more code being required, but may suit your needs.  It worth nothing that char in Java 16-bit rather than 8 bit and a char[] is a separate Object, unlike in C.

In short you can write a library which reads this data without touching the Handshake class.  Only you can decide if this is actually easier than adding a method or two to the handshake class..

Answer (score 0):

Do not do that! I will break sooner or later. Use some binary serialization format, like [Hessian][1], which supports both java and C++ (I'm not aware of anything that works on plain C)
Also remember C does not force size for int's or long's, they are platform dependent. 
So if you must use C, and you are forced to write your own library, be very careful.